# How to check an Elementor widget is loaded?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor, wordpress-plugin-creation

I want to check an Elementor widget is loaded into Elementor edit mode/page. So there is any way(by code) to check specific widget is loaded into a page.

For example: If loaded Team widget then I want to echo "true" and if not then echo "false".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Elementor page content data is in the post meta, so you can check the page's `_elementor_controls_usage` post meta value for list of loaded widgets:

```
$elementor_data = get_post_meta($post_id, '_elementor_controls_usage', true);
if(array_key_exists('team', $elementor_data)){
    echo 'true';
}
else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

For the widget content and other data, use `_elementor_data`